# how to download specific pip version on linux redhat

Tags: python, curl, pip

we can download the latest pip as

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1734k  100 1734k    0     0   164k      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:--  207k
```

the pip :

```
ls
get-pip.py
```

now we install it

```
python get-pip.py

pip --version
pip 19.3 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

**what in case we want the old pip version - 8.1.2**

then how we can use curl to download specific pip version as 8.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo pip install pip==8.1.2
```

It will install the 8.1.2 and remove the newest.